# How do I fix git-credential-manager issue in WSL2?

Tags: git, github, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10 with WSL2.
Recently, I am finding it difficult to `git push origin` to my repo.
It always return this error

> /mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager.exe get: 1: /mnt/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager.exe: not found

After, it asks for my github username and password, it still returns the above error with an addition '*Everything up-to-date*'.

> /mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager.exe store: 1: /mnt/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager.exe: not found
> Everything up-to-date

I have tried this solution below, but it is not working also.

> git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager.exe"

How do I fix this issue please?

Comment: Install git on wsl itself instead of relying on git for windows. Alternatively, did you install a git update recently that added Credential Manager Core? In that case you may need to tweak your global git config in WSL to call that instead of the old credential manager.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Yes, I actulally installed git on wsl itself. From wsl ubuntu in windows terminal I can access `git`, but I cannot access it from powershell. 
And using `sudo apt-get install git` on windows terminal, returns 
>git is already the newest version (1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3).

I updated and upgraded ubuntu yesterday. I don't really know if that's what caused the issue.

Comment: Check your path environment setting to make sure it's finding the WSL one first.

Comment: Please, how do I check the path environmental setting?

Comment: https://opensource.com/article/17/6/set-path-linux

Answer (score 5):

Run as WSL2/root :

```
file=/usr/bin/git-credential-manager
echo 'exec "/c/Program Files/git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager.exe" $@' > $file
chmod +x $file
```

then run as normal user (ubuntu for example)

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.gitconfig
[credential]
    helper = manager
EOF
```

Comment: I did exactly as you advised, it still gave the error when I try to `git push origin`.

I had to activate ssh in ubuntu and github to see if it would work.

It didn't return the error, but "Everything is up-to-date". So I assumed I was making some mistakes. Checking `git status` I noticed that I haven't staged and committed some files. I did and tried `git push origin` again... 

Viola, it finally committed without an error.

Thanks for your assistance

@jessehouwing Thanks for your assistance too.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer a dozen times, but it seems to be returning back to 0 vote.
I am new to this platform, so don't mind my ignorance.

Comment: I had to change the path for the git-credential-manager.exe to /mnt/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager.exe.

Comment: It seems like a WSL1 solution to me, not WSL2

Comment: This recommendation, which is a slight variation of the answer above, worked for me:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-git#git-credential-manager-setup
In a nutshell:
`git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager-core.exe"`

Comment: My WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04.4 looked like this `/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-credential-manager-core.exe get: 1: /mnt/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-credential-manager-core.exe: not found` and was solved by running `git config --global credential.helper store`.

Comment: Thank you so much @skinnedpanda! I tried everything above but this was the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: worked for me, however, I also needed to add 
`git config --global credential.useHttpPath true`

Answer (score 4):

Adding @skinnedpanda's comment as an answer.

Run this in git bash:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

Answer (score 1):

The git credential manager path is changed in newer git versions. So in wsl set new path of credential.helper with :

```
git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-credential-manager-core.exe"
```

`git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager-core.exe`  is changed to `Git/mingw64/bin/git-credential-manager-core.exe`

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8395